# Streams Collectors.summingDouble dynamic function argument

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have following code which works great if i hard-code pojo method **Employee::getBaseSalary**

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Double>> $r = list
                                .stream()
                                .filter((p) -> (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getActiveInd(), "Y")
                                                && CoreUtils.greaterThanOrEquals(p.getCreateDate(), paramDate) && (null == p.getEmpDate())))
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dateFn,
                                         Collectors.groupingBy(empCodeFn,
                                         Collectors.summingDouble(Employee::getBaseSalary))));
```

**Question**

Notice that i have java Function Objects used *dateFn* and *empCodeFn* in group by clause. I am trying to do the same for *summingDouble* as follows but it give compile errors??

```
    private Function<Employee, Double> getFunctionSpecialCalc() {
    switch (calculationType) {
        case BaseSalary:
            return Employee::getBaseSalary;
        case TotalSalary:
            return Employee::getTotalSalary;
        default:
            return Employee::getBaseSalary;
    }
}
```

And i am intended to use it as follows:

```
Function<Employee,Double> calcFn = getFunctionSpecialCalc();
...
...    
Collectors.summingDouble(calcFn))));
```

**Compile Error**
The method summingDouble(ToDoubleFunction) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (Function)

I understand that it needs now function type as *ToDoubleFunction*, but now issue is how to inject dynamically function into SummingDouble?

**Solution** 
After investigation, i have found following solution. Its not that great and clean as using Function Object. Please update if you have **better** solution to the problem.

```
        Collectors.summingDouble((o)->{if(Type.BaseSalary.equals(calculationType)) 
      return o.getBaseSalary();
 else return o.getTotalSalary();
}))));
```

Comment: but it give compile errors: why don't you **read**, and **post** that error? DimTask::getSalary doesn't look like a function taking an Employee as argument to me.

Comment: I have updated the code, and error detail

Comment: When the compiler tells you that you have to use `ToDoubleFunction` instead of `Function`, just replace `Function<Employee,Double>` with `ToDoubleFunction<Employee>`. Why on Earth do you change other things irrelevant to the compiler error?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should do that step in the `collect` part; instead it should be part of some `map` one. But since this is part of a `Collector` I would go with a `Collectors.mapping`, like so:

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Double>> $r = list
       .stream()
       .filter((p) -> (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getActiveInd(), "Y")
                                            && CoreUtils.greaterThanOrEquals(p.getCreateDate(), paramDate) && (null == p.getEmpDate())))
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dateFn,
             Collectors.groupingBy(empCodeFn,
             Collectors.mapping(o-> {
                   if(Type.BaseSalary.equals(calculationType)) 
                        return o.getBaseSalary();
                   else return o.getTotalSalary();
             }, Collectors.summingDouble(x -> x)
   ))));
```

Comment: There is no need to re-evaluate `Type.BaseSalary.equals(calculationType)` in every function evaluation. You can use `Type.BaseSalary.equals(calculationType)? o -> o.getBaseSalary(): o -> o.getTotalSalary()` instead. Or with method references `Type.BaseSalary.equals(calculationType)? Employee::getBaseSalary: Employee::getTotalSalary`. Which is equivalent to the OP’s original approach, the only obstacle is to use `ToDoubleFunction<Employee>` instead of `Function<Employee, Double>` when the compiler tells that a `ToDoubleFunction` is expected…